# Restarting from where recorder left off and Iteration number

Tags: openmdao

I have 2 questions on the case recorder.

1- I am not sure how to restart an optimizaiton from where the recorder left off. I can read in the case reader sql file etc but can not see how this can be fed into the problem() to restart.

2- this question is maybe due to my lack of knowledge in python but how can one access to the iteration number from within an openmdao component (one way is to read the sql file that is constantly being updated but there should be a more efficient way.)

Answer (score 0):

You can re-load a case back via the `load_case` method on the problem. 
See the docs for it [here.](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/2.3.1/features/recording/getting_values.html#loading-cases-into-problems)

Im not completely sure what you mean by access the iteration count, but if you just want to know the number of times your components are called you can add a counter to them yourself.

There is not a programatic API for accessing the iteration count in OpenMDAO as of version 2.3

Comment: i will look at the load_case example thank you.

yes that is what i mean with iteration count , so a specific component's call counter.

Comment: i will look at the load_case example thank you.

yes that is what i mean with iteration count , so a specific component's call counter.
isnt this data recorder already in the recorder as i can see this information once the simulation is finished and sql file is read? so how come it is not accesible on the fly?

when you say add a counter to them do you mean a single number increasing within the def compute?